# Call a url and get a response php

Tags: php

Hi guys im trying to call a url and get some json from it, this is the url

`https://api.sandbox.blackhawknetwork.com/productCatalogManagement/v1/productCatalogs`

can you help me with this?

Comment: `file_get_contents()`  or use `CURL` OF PHP

Comment: Please take a look at php.net; functions like ``file_get_contents()`` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your [HTTP-options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php)
   These tell the stream what to do.
2. Open a stream with [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
3. Read all response data with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Looks like this:

```
$opts = [ 'http' => [
    'header' => [ /* what headers you want */ ],
    'method' => 'GET'
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$content = file_get_contents("URL", false, $context);
```